# How to save a TensorFlow Hub model in SavedModels format?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I'd like to load a model from TensorFlow Hub and save it to disk. I tried:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

def save_module(url, save_path):
  with tf.Graph().as_default():
    module = hub.load(url)
    tf.saved_model.save(module, save_path)

save_module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4", "./saved-module")
```

But this fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\project\python-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1365, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\project\python-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1349, in _run_fn
    return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
  File "C:\project\python-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1441, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    return tf_session.TF_SessionRun_wrapper(self._session, options, feed_dict,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable EncoderDNN/DNN/ResidualHidden_2/dense/kernel/part_27 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/EncoderDNN/DNN/ResidualHidden_2/dense/kernel/part_27)
     [[{{node EncoderDNN/DNN/ResidualHidden_2/dense/kernel/part_27/Read/ReadVariableOp}}]]
     [[EncoderDNN/DNN/ResidualHidden_3/dense/kernel/part_22/Read/ReadVariableOp/_287]]
  (1) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable EncoderDNN/DNN/ResidualHidden_2/dense/kernel/part_27 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/EncoderDNN/DNN/ResidualHidden_2/dense/kernel/part_27)
     [[{{node EncoderDNN/DNN/ResidualHidden_2/dense/kernel/part_27/Read/ReadVariableOp}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

The answer must use the TensorFlow 2 API. Ideally, I want to accomplish this without Keras but I'll also accept answers that use it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get this working without Keras, but in any case this works:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub


def save_module(url, save_path):
  module = hub.KerasLayer(url)
  model = tf.keras.Sequential(module)
  tf.saved_model.save(model, save_path)


save_module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4", "./saved-module")
```

Comment: I get `Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7faf02e0d438>, because it is not built` unfortunately